# Como inserir registros ao iniciar o sistema JSF + JPA?

Tags: jsf, jpa

Como faço para inserir registros pré-cadastrados no sistema com jsf e jpa. Quero que quando o sistema inicie o usuário administrador seja criado.

Comment: Por que não usar scripts SQL? eu penso que é uma péssima idéia fazer isso, muito provável que você só vai executar uma única vez, imagine que você estai criando algo dentro da aplicação que precisa sempre ficar verificando se foi criado, você poderia até mesmo usar uma ferramenta para gerenciar esses scripts como [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/) ou [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) onde você pode ter controle de versionamento dos scripts, é só uma dica, abração.

Comment: Como estou usando JPA, eu teria que acessar o sistema e depois voltar no servidor de bando de dados para executar o script

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a anotação @PostConstruct no método do seu managedBean.
Essa anotação irá fazer com que o método seja invocado após o seu mBean ser instanciado.

Exemplo:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TesteMBean{

    private UserAdm userAdm;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
          userAdm = new UserAdm();
    }

    public UserAdm getUserAdm() {
        return userAdm;
    }

    public void setUserAdm(UserAdm userAdm) {
        this.userAdm = userAdm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção é implementar um [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) e inserir os registros no método contextInitialized, que é invocado quando o servidor inicializa o contexto da aplicação. Dessa forma não é preciso acessar a aplicação para que essa primeira ação (inserir os registros) seja executada.

E o ServletContextListener é gerenciado pelo servidor de aplicação, ou seja, é possível acessar recursos como EntityManager.

```
@Inject
private EntityManager em;
```

Além disso, se utilizar um Managed Bean JSF, o método anotado com @PostConstruct será executado toda vez que a página jsf correspondente for carregada, enquanto o método contextInitialized será carregado apenas uma vez, quando o servidor iniciar a aplicação.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Aplicação xyz iniciada: ");
    sb.append(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    gravarRegistrosPreCadastrados(); //TODO
}
```

Comment: A questão é como executo este sql no meu sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, complementando o que o Paulo Cardoso disse, vc pode usar o @PostConstruct em um determinado Managed Bean e aplicar o @ApplicationScoped, dessa forma, ele será executado somente um vez quando você acessar a aplicação.

```
@Named(value = "tarefasBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class TarefasBean implements Serializable {

public TarefasBean() {
    System.out.println("INICIANDO TAREFAS BEAM");
}

@PostConstruct
public void executarTarefas() {
    verificarConexão();
    iniciarQuartz();
}

private void iniciarQuartz() {
   //iniciando agenda de tarefas aki
}

public void verificarConexão() {
    //meu codigo aki
}

}
```

No método verifica conexão, caso haja um problema, o user será redirecionado, se estiver tudo certo, eu inicio minha "agenda de tarefas", e isso só vai acontecer o primeiro acesso da aplicação. Daí, vc pode fazer suas inserções e coisas do tipo no posconstruct.